# I ruined my gaming keyboard with my own usb driver

Tags: linux, usb, drivers, keyboard

Some time ago, I decided to write a Linux driver for X7 G800V gaming keyboard so that I could program it without Windows.

I made a deadly mistake in the code and uploaded faulty data and now it is dead. It no longer shows up under `lsusb` and Windows says "USB descriptor request failed". I can no longer attach to the device via `libusb`. Even its own Windows driver can't see the keyboard now.

Is there any way I could still recover it?

Comment: Sounds like you have bricked the keyboard.  Unless there is a way to program it other than USB, then the firmware to the keyboard, cannot be restored.

Comment: You are at the point where the manufacturer would probably dismantle the keyboard, plug a programmer into a special debug connector, and then write the firmware directly to the processor. Chances are that USB flashing support requires a functional firmware to begin with which you no longer have so unless you can find the debug connector, a compatible programming device and the actual firmware then you may simply be out of luck. Most of the programmers are quite generic, as are the connectors so again you could be lucky...